# Is there anything like RadWindo in Dojo?

Tags: dojo

Is there anything like RadWindo in Dojo?
I want to open a pop-up style page.
I would love to see any examples people might have.

In RadWindow I would do something like this:

```
       `RadWindow statusWindow = new RadWindow();
        statusWindow.NavigateUrl = "./StatusWindow.aspx" + qs;
        statusWindow.ID = "sendWindow";
        statusWindow.Visible = true;
        statusWindow.Height = Unit.Pixel(180);
        statusWindow.Width = Unit.Pixel(595);
        statusWindow.Modal = true;`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dojo Dialog combined with contentpane:

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/dialogs_tooltips/
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/dialogs_tooltips/demo/dialog-terms.html

Comment: vijay i need to open status window page that has some actions and the page should look like popup. it has to perform some action while loading and after loaded.. the page should look like a popup

Comment: So when you click the "View Terms and Conditions" button, the overlay that displays looks like a popup - no? Dijit dialog provides ability to wire up your own functions onShow, onHide etc

Comment: ya on click of send button it should open a page look like popup and it should have all the properties that a page have. and it would display status of the send operation

Comment: so the dialog will give you a popup like overlay with close button - you will need to write the HTML that goes inside it, that shows the status of the operation - Dojo also offers progress indicators - http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/ProgressBar.html